# Implementing NbRoleProvider

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

I'm implementing an `NbRoleProvider` in my `Angular` application with `Nebular`.

I've implemented it as follow:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleProvider implements NbRoleProvider {

    constructor(private store: Store<IAppStore>) {
    }

    getRole(): Observable<string[]> {

        const loggedUser = this.store.select<IUser>(x => x.loggedUserStore.loggedUser);

        let result = [];
        loggedUser.subscribe(data => {
            if (data != null) {
                result = data.roles; // returns ['admin']
            }
        });
        return of(result);

        // this works!!
        // return of(['admin']);
    }
}
```

If I return a fixed array role like `['admin']` all works like expected. If I try to subscribe the value from the store it won't works. Debugging I see that the `getRole` method is called several times when the `data` object is still `null` and then several time when it has been loaded with proper array list.

It seems that `*nbIsGranted` directive is rendered in the first moment when subscribe is still wait the data from the store.

What I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try returning Observable directly from store like:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RoleProvider implements NbRoleProvider {

    constructor(private store: Store<IAppStore>) {}

    getRole(): Observable<string[]> {
      const loggedUser = this.store.select<IUser>(x => x.loggedUserStore.loggedUser);

      return loggedUser.pipe(map(data => data ? data.roles : []));
    }
}
```